# Django view and separate processes

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing

I would like to do something similar:

f(n) calculates n! , this obviously takes a long time to do, so the calculations need to run in a separate process from the django view. Additionally I would like the view to return a response immediately (ex.  progress 0% ) and subsequent polling needs to update progress, so the view needs to communicate with the above process.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: this should probably be kicked off to a task queue

Comment: I am trying django-tasks right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrey Fedoseev gave a great suggestion, but let me come up with a more general solution. You can create some WaitingTasks model into which where your view puts new tasks. Then, there can use any method to process those waiting tasks - cronjob, upstart daemon, whatever - writing back progress and result.

(In fact `celery` uses a similar approach, only with RabbitMQ)

Answer (score 6):

Try [django-celery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the strategy contained in this link to great affect: [Signals in Django](http://www.chrisdpratt.com/2008/02/16/signals-in-django-stuff-thats-not-documented-well/). The section on "Handling Signals Asynchronously" where the python threading module is used is what I used.

The signals code is pretty out of date (even though it is at the top of a Google search). Still, the threading code is probably what may help you the most.